# How to change Gender Label?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to change Gender label and value in back end? Instead of Gender I need Test. Drop down value yes or No

Comment: Like daniel said, you need to use a translation to change Gender to Test, and Marius explains how to change Male and Female in response to David's question last year

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: You haven't said what "it" is. You might also like to list the steps you took as you understood them

Answer (score 0):

From the top menu :

Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes, select Gender, then go to Manage Label / Options

Comment: i am asking for customer gender option and label

Comment: Ah. You should change the original question to include that. Is there a reason you don't just add a new attribute called 'test'?

Comment: Oh sorry is it possible change customer label

Answer (score 0):

> Backend -> System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Translate Inline -> Enable for Frontend

You then can change the label in the frontend.
But thats not how it should be done if you want another / new attribute

Comment: i want to change customer attribute gender into - > test and Male/Female into -> Yes or No